# Edit data in Partial Views ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a serious problem with my current project and need help to solve it.

Here in my project, in the main create view there is,

*Main Create view and
*A couple of partial views

loaded according to the Main Create view data. When the user saves it, the data will be saved in the database.

When the user clicks on the Edit button Edit view also shows without any error.

Think User did changes on the Main Create view data and some data in partial views and clicks to the update button, only the Main Create view data will be updated. Partial view data will not update. It remains the same.

But instead of updating, there will be another record will be saved in the database with the new data.

It's a bit complicated to describe this error. Hope you understand the issue.

This is how the Edit code wrote in the project.

```
if (appRequest.GeneralItmsList != null) {

  db.Entry(appRequest).State = EntityState.Modified;
  for (int y = 0; y < appRequest.GeneralItmsList.Count; y++) {
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ImageData" + appRequest.GeneralItmsList[y].TempID];

    if (file != null) {
      appRequest.GeneralItmsList[y].Attachment = ConvertToBytes(file);
    } else {
      db.Entry(appRequest).Property(x => x.GeneralItmsList[y].Attachment).IsModified = false;
    }

  }

  appRequest.General = new List < General > () {
    new General {
      GeneralItms = appRequest.GeneralItmsList,

    }
  };
```

Comment: Are you new to MVC? It sounds like you have created a complicated project w/o fully understanding how MVC works. Have you worked through the MS tutorials? You should fully understand how the simple works before you try the complicated.

Comment: @John Yes, I'm new to MVC and followed some tutorials and did self studies.